# jhipster fine grain authorization, remove ROLE based authorization

Tags: spring, jhipster

I have been searching on how to remove the ROLE based authorization and replace it with fine grain authorization. What I meant by fine grain is 
All method has a @PreAuthorize("isAuthorize('GETCLIENT')") or directly @IsAuthorize("GETCLIENT").
If the user has GETCLIENT in Authorization List, then the method can be executed. Otherwise, the system give error message or just deny access.
Any clue or information regarding how to do that is very much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: You can define your own authorities in `AuthoritiesConstants.java` and use `@Secured({AuthoritiesConstants.GETCLIENT})`. Is that what you need?

Comment: Thanks vicpermir for pointing out a simple solution. I really overlooked this possibility. In fact, I looked around extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration and really confused about it. Is there any reference or websites where I can get a better grip on the understanding of how the jhipster security working behind the scene? Thanks again.

Comment: I've answered and expanded a bit on those topics with links, hope you can make it work.

Comment: Thank you very much vicpermir. The information you provided really help me and enlighten me on possibilities of doing various things in jhipster. Again. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in the comment one quick and easy way to do this is to add your new custom authorities in the `AuthoritiesConstants.java` class. You have examples of how to do this [here](https://www.jhipster.tech/tips/025_tip_create_new_authority.html) and [here](https://blog.ippon.tech/improving-the-access-control-of-a-jhipster-application/).

```java
public final class AuthoritiesConstants {

    public static final String ADMIN = "ROLE_ADMIN";

    public static final String USER = "ROLE_USER";

    public static final String ANONYMOUS = "ROLE_ANONYMOUS";

    public static final String GETCLIENT = "ROLE_GETCLIENT"; // custom

    private AuthoritiesConstants() {
    }
}
```

Remember to insert the new role into your `jhi_authority` database table. You can assign new authorities to a user via the user management interface `admin/user-management`, it's possible the user needs to relog for the change to take effect.

Then in the method you want to secure just add:

```java
    @GetMapping("/clients/{id}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole(\"" + AuthoritiesConstants.GETCLIENT + "\")")
    public ResponseEntity<ClientDTO> getClient(@PathVariable Long id) {
        log.debug("REST request to get Client : {}", id);
        Optional<ClientDTO> clientDTO = clientService.findOne(id);
        return ResponseUtil.wrapOrNotFound(clientDTO);
    }
```

I said `@Secured` before but in reality you should use `@PreAuthorize` since it is more powerful and lets you work with [Spring Expression Language (SpEL)](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions).

The go to resource to understand how JHipster security works is [here](https://www.jhipster.tech/security/), but in reality it just follows the standard Spring Security guidelines (as with many other things) so the official documentation about [Spring Security](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security) should apply too.

Also, if you find this is too simple or that it is breaking the default conventions I found [this guide](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-create-new-custom-security-expression) about custom privileges to be particularly great. It's a bit more work, but should work better since you separate authorities (roles) from privileges.

Comment: Thanks. Very useful and easy to understand.

Comment: When I set up CRUD access for my own entity, I also need to comment out //            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated(). After commenting out, then the system work properly.

Comment: That's not a very good idea, you are opening up all your api routes. I have updated my answer after doing some tests, hopefully I got it right this time :)

Comment: You are right. In fact, when I commented out .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated(), the system automatically login in as user anonymoususer. Actually, when we add an authority, it won't work directly, we need to logout and login again to see the effect. As a note, I follow the instruction from jhipster website by updating the target/classes/config/liquibase/data/authority.csv. Somehow, the liquibase does not perform adding the data into jhi_authority. So I add it manually using sql INSERT.